# WebSocket и https

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Ребят помогите с настройками для `https` соединения.
Есть настройки для `ws://` протокола:

Клиент:
sockethost = 'домен.зона'
socketport = '8080'

Сервер:
sockethost = 'localhost'
socketport = '8080'

Все работает нормально на `http`, как только настроили `https` и стали использовать протокол `wss://` перестало работать.

Также использую `домен.зона` и `443` порт при соединении с сервером тоже ставлю `443` порт, но выбивает ошибку:

> Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [13]: Permission denied

А если пытаюсь сервер поднимать на любом другом порту, сервер поднимается, но при попытке коннекта с клиента, выбивает ошибку:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://домен.зона:2424/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Сертификат (не самоподписанный, как сказал сисадмин) сертификат от https://www.comodo.com/ но он бесплатный.

Не понимаю из-за чего это может происходить, уже перерыл весь интернет ничего не помогает.

Возможно не так что-то делаем, пожалуйста помогите.

Как правильно поднимать сервер и что писать в клиенте?

Comment: Посмотри здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689721/cant-use-port-80-or-443-for-websocket-on-xampp

Comment: Если у вас установлено на рабочей машине антивирусное ПО, советую отключить его)
Возможно антивирус блокирует доступ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема в бесплатном сертификате.

Answer (score -3):

1. Используйте домен на который выданный сертификат.
2. Порт 8080 не может использоваться для защищенных соединений. Попробуйте как пример 443 или 8443. Порты должны быть открыти на вашем сервере.

Comment: Уже так и делаем, но возникла новая ошибка: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH с чем она связана?